# Blood type stats

Tags: statistics

Suppose 20% of people have blood type A, 20% of people have blood type B, 50% of people have blood type O, and 10% of people have blood type AB.

We can find the probability that both parents have blood type AB is 0.01.  We assume that if both parents have blood type AB, the probability that their child also has blood type AB is 0.50.  Given that your friend has blood type AB, what is the conditional probability that your friend’s parents both have blood type AB?

I found out all the values, by assuming the events. however I got stuck on finding the Probability of my friend having blood type AB. will we take it as 10% of people having blood type AB

Comment: See [Bayes Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Comment: 10% seems like the reasonable thing to take, yes. @WaveX While I agree with you that this is a typical Bayes' theorem problem, this is not what the question is about.